# Redirecting standard output to pipe and then reading different length integers from it

Tags: c++, c, pipe

I have redirected the program's standard output to pipe. The only output are random 0 - 10^9 integers, up to 10 digits. In the other program I am reading the pipe.

Now, my problem is the handling the received data. If I define the `char` buffer at length 10 + 1, then if the sent number has less than 10 digits the data starts getting messy. I receive some kind of trash, extra zeroes etc.

Since the standard output sends the data as a text, I can't use the `int` as the buffer, since it takes only 4 bytes so the first 4 digits and cuts the rest of the number;

My question is: is there a possible solution for that?

I printed an output of the buffer. I have sent 10x `1000`, the result is:
31 30 30 30 0a 31 30 30 30 0a 31
30 30 30 0a 31 30 30 30 0a 31 30
30 30 0a 31 30 30 30 0a 31 30 30
30 0a 31 30 30 30 0a 31 30 30 30
0a 31 30 30 30 0a 0a 31 30 30 30

So all lines have 11 bytes as intended. But there is a carriage return at line 1 in the middle and then the next number appears. I guess the arithmetic to count the bytes until the carriage return and then taking the next few bytes as a number until another carriage return would get a bit ugly.

Maybe the way that I took is wrong, like there is no clear solution for the problem and it would be better to take another approach? My intention was to write a tester program for an C++ app. The tester sends the data line by line, and then takes the output from the C++ program line by line too and checks if the returned output is correct. The C++ app takes the input data only by standard input / output, that's the main limitation. It's pretty easy to accomplish this in other languages but here it got little messy I guess.

Comment: Please show the attempt you have made so far.

Comment: Can you just read one line to a `std::string` (with `std::getline` say), and then convert the string to a number? I really don't see the problem. Since your numbers are whitespace separated you could even just use `>>`.

Comment: Use some kind of a delimiter. The simplest one is the new line `\n` so that default I/O functions will read it line by line for you, as @john remarked.

Comment: Well, thanks for the tips. I am beginner at C++ so the streams are pretty new to me. One major thing is that data is stored in a char array. I am getting the data from a pipe: `read(parent_pipe_fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))`. Not sure if there was some better way to communicate these two programs. However I will try to use streams.

Comment: @Jakub I missed that you are reading from a pipe, you might be able to wrap a C++ stream around a file descriptor, but it's not standard C++ if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is one number per line (with `0x0a` to split the lines). So simply read a line at a time.

```
int main()
{
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << "Got Line: " << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. I tried smth similiar at my own according to the tips in the comments, but the source of data is the `pipe()`.  I am getting the data from a `read(parent_pipe_fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))`  where the buffer is a char array[11] and it stores the data.

Comment: Why are you doing that manually in the code. Let the OS do the hard work. Redirect stdin/stdout at the application level so that you can use this as a normal stream.: `randomnumberGenerator | myApplication`.

Comment: Alternatively you can always write a custom stream buffer that reads from a pipe but that is not something I would expect a beginner to do.